# Arch Linux - How could I decrypt and automount multiple encrypted drives during init?

Tags: arch-linux, automounting, init, disk-encryption, whole-drive-encryption

I have two encrypted drives (one SSD for booting and a hard drive for storage) I need both to be unlocked and mounted before all of the runlevel programs/services. Else some of my services would freak out when they can't find my storage drive.

Currently, when I boot from my fully encrypted drive I get the following:

```
A password is required to access the root volume:
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda1
```

What I'd like to happen is:

```
A password is required to access the root volume:
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda1
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb1
```

So I type in the key of /dev/sda1, then the key for /dev/sdb1 and then /dev/sdb1 is mounted. After this the system continues to boot.

Comment: You add `/sdb1` to your [crypttab file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#crypttab).

Answer (score 2):

jasonwryan's solution would work for most users so if anyone is reading this who uses Arch Linux with systemd (vanilla Arch Linux) then do that.

However, in my case I use OpenRC. I followed [this Gentoo wiki guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Dm-crypt#Configuring_dm-crypt) though I wasn't quite sure what the "target=" line meant.

To manually unlock my device I run "cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 lvm" since it has an LVM partition and according to IRC the formatting for the luksOpen command is "cryptsetup luksOpen $source $target".

So I stole Gentoo's dmcrypt OpenRC init script and pasted it in /etc/init.d/dmcrypt. Then I stole the default config file and pasted it in /etc/conf.d/dmcrypt. I then added the following to the bottom of the config file:

```
target=lvm
source=UUID="insertUUIDhere"
```

Then I added dmcrypt to the default runlevel with "rc-update add dmcrypt default".

The device now prompts to be decrypted on boot :).